# 1-Factorization of complete Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

We have a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) graph $K_n$ with $n$ vertices.

Then the number of distinct  [1-factorizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#Complete_graphs) of a $K_n$ graph for $K_2$, $K_4$, $K_6$, $K_8$ is 1, 1, 6, 6240 respectively. (see [A000438](https://oeis.org/A000438)).

I wanted to understand these numbers, but I failed already for the example $K_4$. In my attempts, I would get 3 different 1-factorizations, not one:

[image: 1-Factorization of $K_4$]

Could you please tell me what I misunderstand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 1-factor is a spanning subgraph, while a 1-factorization of $K_n$ is the partition of $K_n$ into multiple 1-factors.

In the example given in the question, $K_4$ is partitioned into three 1-factors, but there is only one unique way to do that.

As another example, there are 6 ways to 1-factorize $K_6$ into 5 1-factors, as illustrated in the figures below.

[image: 1-Factorization of $K_6$]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know what I am doing is wrong, but still I dont see the reason. For a $K_6$ graph I should get 6 distinct factorizations. Could you maybe give an example how these distinct factorizations look like? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ahh I was confusing factors with factorization. That makes perfect sense. Thank you!